# Presenting multiple lines of text in JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable, I Want to present a String of text containing "\r\n" which represent new lines. And I want these new lines to show in the table and not just be ignored.
A visual representation of my problem follows.

Today:

```
|Titel           |
------------------
|texttex ttext xt|
------------------
```

Goal:

```
  |Titel   |
  ----------
  |texttex |
  |ttext xt|
  ----------
```

I have experimented with JTextPane but my result is a textual representation of that object instead of a text encapsulated in a JTextPane..(Maybe I don't understand all those obvious internet guides).

To summarize the question, how do I present a column in a JTable which contains multiple lines without having a indexation for each line.
(or basic instructions of how to really make the JTextPane work in a column..?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest either you use `<br>` instead of `\r\n`
or
you set a `TableCellRenderer` on your `JTable`. The `TableCellRenderer` would return a `JTextPane` when it is called - create only one instance of `JTextPane` and return it for each call (after having set the appropriate value)

Comment: hi, can u please tell me how to add new line in jtable cell as I need to have multiple lines in jtable cell.

Answer (score 3):

see [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html),

1. [basic instructions of how to realy make the JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867849/714968)
2. event is example about `JTextArea`, have to change to `JTextPane` and to add `JTextPane#setContentType(text/html)`, look into API
3. issue could be with `SystemLookAndFeel` and `JTextPane as JTables Renderer`