# Unable to Call the JTable Cellrenderer in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `MultilineCellRenderer` which should wrap the multiple lines in `JTable` cell.

```
public class MultiLineTableCellRenderer 
        extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public MultiLineTableCellRenderer() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                Object value, boolean isSelected,
                                boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setText(value.toString());//or something in value, like value.getNote()..
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),
            getPreferredSize().height);
        if (table.getRowHeight(row) != getPreferredSize().height) {
            table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

I am creating and assigning this `cell renderer` as `default cell renderer` for `myjtable(cnr_DATA)`

```
MultiLineTableCellRenderer r = new MultiLineTableCellRenderer();
cnr_DATA.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, r);
cnr_DATA.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data,columns){
    public Class getColumnClass(int col){
        return String.class;
    };
});
```

I am also updating the content of jtable dynamically from the database

```
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)cnr_DATA.getModel();
```

removeAllCurrentRows(model);

```
Vector<DocumentRow> data = 
    RecycleSQL.readRecycledDocuments();//this line returning vector of objects
for(DocumentRow object:data)
    model.addRow(new string[]{object.getFilename(),
            object.getTitle(),object.getLastTouched()
                            ,object.getLastTouchedBy()});
model.setRowCount(data.size());
cnr_DATA.revalidate();
```

My problem is that `mycellrenderer` is not being called and is not wrapping the data. Could some one please advice me how to call it after updating the content of the `JTable`.

**Update according to the suggestion of Madprogrammer and hovercraft**

After modifying the code according to the suggestion. Now the `cellrenderer` is being called but it is resting the row height to default value. This is the logs from debug statement

```
[2013-08-02 01:20:53,335] [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG MultiLineTableCellRenderer  - setting row height 3  128
[2013-08-02 01:20:53,335] [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG MultiLineTableCellRenderer  - setting row height 3  16
```

which means, that after setting the height of the row correctly it is resting it back to the default value

Comment: I suspect that the call to `setModel` may be resetting the default editors and it will be changing the column model.  You might want to swap those statements

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get what do you want me to change (swap)

Comment: Swap setting model and the renderer so that the model is set first and then the renderer

Comment: Finally fixed. I will provide the answer. Thanks a lot for hints

Comment: the removeAll looks fishy: a) setRowCount is not needed after adding rows b) table.revalidate is not needed, provided the model complies to its notification contract (which DefaultTableModel does) If any of these seems to "fix" a problem, you are doing something wrong which has to be found and _really_ fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This looks suspect to me:

```
cnr_DATA.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, r); // ?? String.class
```

Are you sure that the model holds **String** data, and that the column type returned by `getColumnClass(...)` returns String?  Consider instead setting the cell renderer for the column that needs it.

Comment: yes, it is storing string[] and the column type is string. I have modified my code according to that.

Comment: From memory, `DefaultTableModel#getColumnClass` returns `Object`. The OP needs to override this method to return `String` - I'm giving you +1 cause you're close and I know you'll verify and update as required (besides, you're so close to 3 digits) ;)

Comment: Finally I have fixed it. I am going to write the answer now. Thanks a lot for your hints you are always great

Comment: [see basic stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12867849/714968), note carrefully with doLayout, is proper method for reasonable number of chars in JTextArea as renderers component, otherwise you need to use JScrollPane for JTextArea too, that I can't see in your renderer too