# JList setMimimumSize() inside a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, border-layout

I have a `JScrollPane` which has a `JList` inside;

```
    instructionsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(instructionList);
```

The `JScrollPane` is itself in a `JPanel` using `BorderLayout`;

```
    panel.add(instructionsScrollPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Now, I am trying to stop the list/scrollpane going below a a certain minimum size when the window is resized, except `JScrollPane` can't have minimum size set, and the list is inside the `JScrollPane` which can't have a `layoutManager`. So I am unable to set the minimum size of the `JList` without a `layoutManager`...

Now, I think I could have the JScrollPane/JList centered using `BorderLayout` inside another `JPanel` (which I would then set a minimum size of) inside this the current `panel`... but that seems messy. Does anyone know of a better way to size ScrollPanes?

I know there is probably a solution using a different `layoutManager`, but I am already committed to using `BorderLayout` at this point.

Comment: don't commit to a _specific_ LayoutManager (at least not to such a poor beast as BorderLayout) - learn about what each has to offer and choose one that fits your requirements best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, I could have the JScrollPane centered using BorderLayout inside
>   another JPanel (which I would set a minimum size of) inside this the
>   current panel... but that seems messy. Does anyone know of a better
>   way to size ScrollPanes?

for JList is very easy, simple to set initial coordinates, returns expected Dimension for LayoutManager, there are two methods implemented in API

- [JList.setPrototypeCellValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28E%29)

  and/or if really needed to restrict 2nd dimension
- [JList.setVisibleRowCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29)

Comment: What's the advantage of using setPrototypeCellValue over using setFixedCellWidth? I'm having a little difficulty understand exactly how setPrototypeCellValue works.

Comment: setPrototypeCellValue(see top of JList API) is used for example, now I'll  talking about String instance only, but is applicable to all data types, you can to compute the longest String lenght before (XxxwwwAAA111eee), then put this value as setPrototypeCellValue(" XxxwwwAAA111eee ")

Comment: Thanks! Looks as though I will be using `setFixedCellWidth()` in the end because a lot of the entries in the list will be very long indeed, and I need to to line up quite precisely with a couple other components.

Comment: `because a lot of the entries in the list will be very long indeed` == [wait, stop, you are going to impasse, make things simpler, otherwise you are prisonier of your ****,  you would need to ....](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12867849/714968)

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks for pointing that out. I will cut short the visible strings before I attach them to the list.